# I cannot paste bold formatting into a RichTextBox in VB.NET Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox, richtext

I want to copy and paste text containing bold formatting from another program (Google Docs) into a RichTextBox in a Windows Form. When I copy and paste text containing bold formatting into the RichTextBox, it comes out as plaintext.

Is there a way I can allow pasting rich text with formatting from another program?

Comment: When pasting from a WebBrowser, the DataObject contains multiple formats: RTF is usually (if not always, when dealing with text) included. It doesn't mean that the RichTextBox implementation of RTF can reproduce everything. Bold style, it surely can.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to work from Docs. It does work when pasting from Word and from some websites.

Comment: Then inspect the DataObject when you paste or drag/drop the content. See what format are available (RTF should be there, but it may come in a MemoryStream in a custom format instead of standard RTF text using a standard format name). You probably (it's common when pasting/dropping from a Web page) have also HTML format, so you could use a WebBrowser control to show the content.

Comment: I don't seem to have any ability to right-click or inspect the RichTextBox when pasting content. It's just Ctrl+V or nothing.

Comment: Handle the Paste event yourself. You need a custom control derived from RichTextBox for that.

Comment: I gave it a look. A Copy/Paste operation performed in Google Docs returns these formats, when pasted in a RTB: `"text/html", "HTML Format", "System.String", "UnicodeText", "Text", "application/x-moz-custom-clipdata"`. All standard formats except `x-moz-custom-clipdata` (using the FireFox browser). This format is a MemoryStream, containing the Document structure and its text, serialized as JSON. No RTF, though. The Docs applet doesn't appear to handle DragDrop outside the document itself.

Comment: Unless I missed something, you may need a HTML to RTF conversion. Or use a WebBroswer control to show the Google Document content, since the HTML format is available.